# Would like the rows with max(date)

Tags: mysql

This works in MYSQL:

```
SELECT hi_Historie_id, 
  hi_Klus_id, 
  hi_Datum_gedaan, 
  hi_Prijs, 
  hi_Voldaan, 
  hi_Datum_voldaan, 
  hi_Voldaan_via, 
  max(hi_next_date), 
  hi_Opmerking
FROM Historie 
GROUP BY hi_Klus_id
```

This gives the right Result: **all the rows with the `hi_Klus_id` with the latest date**.

But than I will make a join with an other table:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN Glazenwassen ON Historie.hi_Klus_id = Glazenwassen.gw_Klus_id 
WHERE Historie.hi_next_date <= CURDATE()
```

This gives the error `#1064`.

Can anybody explain me why?

Comment: please post your full query including the join

Comment: also give the full error not just the code.

Comment: #1064 is a syntax error. show the entire query, and the exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to create a subquery to return the `MAX(hi_next_date)` and then join that result to both the `Historie` and `Glazenwassen` tables:

```
select h.hi_Historie_id, 
  h.hi_Klus_id, 
  h.hi_Datum_gedaan, 
  h.hi_Prijs, 
  h.hi_Voldaan, 
  h.hi_Datum_voldaan, 
  h.hi_Voldaan_via, 
  h.hi_next_date, 
  h.hi_Opmerking
from Historie h
inner join
(
  select max(hi_next_date) hi_next_date, hi_Klus_id
  from Historie
  group by hi_Klus_id
) h2
  on h.hi_Klus_id = h2.hi_Klus_id
  and h.hi_next_date = h2.hi_next_date
left join Glazenwassen g
  on h.hi_Klus_id = g.gw_Klus_id
where h.hi_next_date <= CURDATE()
```

When you join the subquery to the `Historie` table, you will want to join on both the `hi_next_date` and the `hi_Klus_id`.

Comment: This is great. It works. Now onley have to limit the result with: WHERE h.hi_next_date <= CURDATE() Can you tell me where to place that? please, Thank you very much

Comment: @DickiSmits see my edit, you just add the `where` clause at the end

Comment: Bluefeet thanks for your help, That was what i tried by myself and that did give an empty result While the command: SELECT *
FROM Historie
WHERE hi_next_date <= CURDATE( )
give me two rows of result. So there is something not correct i think :-(

Comment: @DickiSmits can you create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with your tables and some sample data?

Comment: Don't know how to do SQL fiddle but you can find the structure here: http://absoluut.org/1/create_dbase.txt

Comment: @DickiSmits Here is fiddle with the tables created -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba2649 -- All you need to do is add some insert statements in the left panel and click `Build Schema`.

Comment: Sorry that goes above my head.

Comment: At this point, I would need to see some data for each table to be able to assist.  I cannot tell why you say this isn't working.

Comment: Did place the data all in www.absoluut.org/1/ in txt files, maybe that helps?

Comment: @DickiSmits Based on the sample data that you provided, you don't have any records where the `hi_next_date` is less than today's date. See this fiddle with the where clause removed -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bdf5/8

Comment: seems your right ??? i am working to long on this for today??? I will look into it tomorrow again. Seems your code is ok so thank you for your patience. have a nice day, greetings from holland

Comment: Happy to help, if this answer is acceptable be sure to accept it via the checkmark on the left.

Comment: With the scrip above it works, I changed the dates to less than today, ok, but it seems that i can't request the fields from the Glazenwassen Table? I would request the gw_Woonplaats, gw_Straatnaam, gw_Huisnummer to put them in the rows in the results but it seems that that columns are not include in the only the results from the Historie tables seems include ? Can you tell me why?

Comment: You have to add them to the select list, see this demo --http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bdf5/14

Comment: Ahh did not know that i can select from Glazenwassen in first select because there was written FROM Historie.  Yes i am new to mysql but learns a lot with you help Great, thanks a lot